# What is the Pythonic way to execute subcommands with special characters in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following shell command I want to run from a Python script:

```
pd schedule:list -j | egrep '\"(name|time_zone)\b.*$$' | awk '/name/ {print $0} /time_zone/ {print $0 "\n"}'
```

---

It's separated as follows:

Print a large list in `.json` format:

```
pd schedule:list -j
```

Pipe the output through `egrep` and capture only the lines with strings `"name"` and `"time_zone"`:

```
| egrep '\"(name|time_zone)\b.*$$'
```

Pipe `egrep` output through `awk` and group every 2 lines:

```
| awk '/name/ {print $0} /time_zone/ {print $0 '\n'}'
```

Send the output of `awk` to `schedules.txt` file:

```
>> schedules.txt
```

Here's an example of the result straight from the terminal:

```
    "name": "1st Line 7-17",
    "time_zone": "Europe/Helsinki",

    "name": "24-5",
    "time_zone": "Europe/Warsaw",

    "name": "Amazon Connect Test",
    "time_zone": "Europe/Warsaw",
    
     ... etc
```

It runs fine in the terminal. But as there's a handful of special characters in the whole command I am having a lot of problems trying to format it so I can print it using the `subprocess` module in Python3.

What is the cleanest Pythonic way to do this? I realise the steps are already a bit much but it's the only way (I understand) to isolate and make readable, this huge .json list I get.

Comment: I don't see any triple quotes in the command, so have you tried `r"""..."""`?

Comment: Remember to use `shell=True` so that the piping works correctly.

Comment: Or, you know that Python can do the same things that `egrep` and `awk` are doing quite easily.

Comment: For some reason I cannot mark @SilvioMayolo's response as an answer. But using an r-string fixed it entirely. Thanks!